# Jackson serialization/deserialization of the tree structure

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson

I have the following POJO classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Folder", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "parent"   
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    FolderTree.class
})
public class Folder
{    
    protected int id;
    protected int parent;

    getters, setters...
}
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "FolderTree", propOrder = {
    "subFolders"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "folderTree")
public class FolderTree extends Folder
{
    @XmlElement(name = "subFolder", type = Folder.class)
    protected List<Folder> subFolders;

    getter...
}
```

and a wrapper:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Folders", propOrder = {
    "folders"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "folders")
public class Folders
{
    @XmlElement(name = "folder", type = Folder.class)
    protected List<Folder> folders;

    getter...
}
```

I need to serialize and deserialize them in XML and JSON. XML works fine, but JSON serializes in the following structure:

```
{
    "folder": [
        {
            "subFolder": [
                {
                    "subFolder": [],
                    "id": 2,
                    "parent": 1

                },
                {
                    "subFolder": [],
                    "id": 3,
                    "parent": 1
                }
            ],
            "id": 1,
            "parent": null            
        }
    ]
}
```

The deserializer can't recognize the second field subFolder inside the subFolder object ("subFolder": []). Is there a way to make it include the subFolder field only in the parent Folder? Or what can be done to make Jackson deserialize that object as it is?

I can't change POJO classes since they are created by jaxb and everything works correctly with XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution.

To get rid of empty subFiolder arrays in case there are no children, I disabled WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS in the serialization features. I use Spring and the bean looks like this:

```
<bean id="objectMapper" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="annotationIntrospector" ref="jaxbAnnotationIntrospector" />
    <property name="featuresToDisable">
        <list>
            <value type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature">WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

For deserialization, since I couldn't modify POJO classes, I added a MixIn for the Folder class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
        property = "folder",
        defaultImpl = FolderTree.class)
public class FolderMixin {

}
```

Finally, I extended ObjectMapper to set MixInAnnotations:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper
{
    public CustomObjectMapper()
    {
        super();
        customize();
    }

    protected void customize()
    {
        registerModule(new SimpleModule() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
                super.setupModule(context);
                context.setMixInAnnotations(Folder.class, FolderMixin.class);
            }         
        });
    }
}
```

And I added both AnnotationIntrospectors for deserialization:

```
<bean id="customObjectMapper" class="path.to.my.CustomObjectMapper"> 
    <property name="annotationIntrospector" ref="introspectors" />
</bean> 

<!-- introspectors  -->
<bean id="xmlAnnotation" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector">
    <constructor-arg value="#{customObjectMapper.getTypeFactory()}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jsonAnnotation" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector" />

<bean id="introspectors" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair">
    <constructor-arg ref="xmlAnnotation" />
    <constructor-arg ref="jsonAnnotation" />
</bean>
<!--  end of introspectors  -->

<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="customObjectMapper"/>
</bean>
```

I use Jackson 2.4.0.